# Should I keep the Apple Developer Team ID secret?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

Is it safe for me to post the Apple Team ID to a public forum (as in, for example, somebody is helping me to troubleshoot an issue and I post my .mobileprovision file, or a generated entitlements file that contains the team id, or I paste snippets of these to Stack Overflow)? Or should I obfuscate it first?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter. This information is generally obtainable in some cases anyway. For instance, to support certain web integrations, an app's site must host a `apple-app-site-association` file with all of the related apps and their bundle ids/ team ids listed.

For example, here is Facebook's:

https://www.facebook.com/apple-app-site-association

Comment: But how about posting the whole `.mobileprovision` file? Is that safe?

Comment: @Thilo I don't think it matters, as you can always go to AppStore and download the IPA file, and get provisioning profile there.